# using r+ to modify text file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// number of salesman 
#define SIZE 100
// salesman_type structure definition
typedef struct{
        int ID; // salesman id
        char id_txt[6]; // salesman id for txt file
        char name[50]; // salesman name
        double hor_total; // total sales amount of a salesman  
    }salesman_type; // end structure salesman_type

salesman_type salesman[SIZE];// synonym for salesman_type 

// function prototype
int sale_menu(); 
void modifySales();

// sales processing system menu function
int sale_menu()
{
    int menu;
    system("cls");
    printf("Sales Processing System\n");
    printf("-----------------------\n\n");
    printf("1. Add Salesman Records\n");
    printf("2. Reports Generation\n");
    printf("3. Modify Salesman Records\n");
    printf("4. Delete Salesman Records\n\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
    printf("Your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &menu);
    return menu;
    printf("\n");
}// end function sale_menu

// modify salesman records function 
void modifySales()
{
    FILE *salesPtr; // sales.txt file pointer
    FILE *salesmanPtr; // salesman.txt file pointer
    int a = 1, b, modify; // counter 
    double sale[SIZE][4]; // quartely sales amount

    // fopen opens the file; exits program if file cannot be opened
    if ( (salesPtr = fopen("sales.txt","r+")) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Cannot open sales.txt\n"); // display error message 
        system("pause"); // pause program before it exits
        exit(-1); // end program 
    } // end if
    else
    {
        // prompt and read salesman id
        printf("\nSalesman ID (NO.): ");
        scanf("%d",&modify);

        // if it is not required salesman id
        while (a != modify)
        {
            fscanf(salesPtr,"%*[^\n]\n");
            a++;
        }

        fscanf(salesPtr,"%*[^|]|", salesman[0].id_txt);
        // read quarterly sales amount
        for (b=0; b<4; b++)
        {   
            // prompt and read quarterly sales amount
            printf("Quarter %d: ", b+1);
            scanf("%lf",&sale[0][b]);
            // end with "|" symbol if b is less than 3
            if(b<3)
            {
                fprintf(salesPtr,"%.2f|",sale[0][b]);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(salesPtr,"%.2f\n",sale[0][b]);
            }
        } // end for
    } // end else
    fclose(salesPtr); // fclose close the file
} // end function modifySales 

// function main begins program execution
int main()
{
    // variable declaration
    int a, b, c = 0, last; // counter
    int getMenu = 10, getReport = 10; // menu selector

    while (getMenu != 0)
    {
        // call and assign sale_menu function to getMenu
        // Execute command based on user input
        switch(getMenu = sale_menu())
        {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                modifySales();
                break;
        } // end switch
    }// end while 
    return 0;
} // end main
```

Steps to reproduce issue
1) Choose 3. Modify Salesman Records
2) input 1 for salesman id
3) all input 1 for quarterly sales amount

I expect the first salesman of quarterly sales amount all change to 1 but it didn't. What's wrong with my code?

text file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5nsdc9j8nwyduu/sales.txt

Comment: Don't forget a file opened in update mode is regulated by several rules (§7.21.5.3#7).

Comment: Your sales.txt is not what you expected - it is html/javascript saved as text...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. You are trying to mix reading and writing of the same file without any attention to where exactly in the file you are writing.  It would be better to read from the old file and write to a new file.

Comment: If I still want to use r+, is there any solution to achieve the goal?